# Как перехватывать ошибку и выводить её индекс?

Tags: python

В моём проекте у меня может возникнуть ошибка в определённом участке кода. Её причина зависит от параметров пользователя.
Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, как это можно устроить? По какой-то причине возникает ошибка в 4 строке. Я хочу сделать обработку исключения (деление на ноль).

```python
try: 
  if a // b: 
    c = "Успешно делится на это число!" 
catch: # Error 
  c = "При делении возникла ошибка!"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кодов ошибок в Python нет, есть [Исключения](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/isklyucheniya-v-python-konstrukciya-try-except-dlya-obrabotki-isklyuchenij.html)

Если вы хотите вывести текст исключения, то используйте такую конструкцию:

```
try:
    print(0 / 0)
except Exception as e:
  print(e) # division by zero
```

Если вы хотите вывести тип исключения, то используйте вот такую конструкцию

```
try:
    print(0 / 0)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.__class__)  # <class 'ZeroDivisionError'>
```